# How to send cURL requests in PHP to jpegmini server on AWS for compressed images

Tags: php, image, curl, amazon-ec2, jpegmini

I have the following requirement
Upload a jpg format image to jpegmini server and receive the compressed image as the response

Please refer to the below jpegmini documentation

Method: POST
URL: http://ec2-54-209-163-171.compute-1.amazonaws.com/api/v1/optimize
Body: The data of the source jpeg photo
Command:
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' --data-binary @/tmp/input.jpg --output /tmp/output.jpg http://ec2-54-209-163-171.compute-1.amazonaws.com/api/v1/optimize

If we break down the above command
-X POST - specify http POST method
-H 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' - specify body content is a jpeg
--data-binary @/tmp/input.jpg - send /tmp/input.jpg as the data of the request
--output /tmp/output.jpg - store response in /tmp/output.jpg (instead of stdout)

Please note that the jpegmini URL is an AWS instance
I am stopping the instance when not using it
If you want me to run the instance please let me know

I want to make this cURL request and receive response using PHP.
Please help me out.

I have tried the the following code 
`$fileDestination = "output.jpg";

```
// Starting output buffering
ob_start();

// create a new CURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ec2-54-209-163-171.compute-1.amazonaws.com/api/v1/optimize');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: image/jpeg'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents("input.jpg"));

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// set timeouts
//set_time_limit(30);                     // set time in secods for PHP
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);  // and also for CURL

// open a stream for writing
$outFile = fopen($fileDestination, 'wb');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $outFile);

// grab file from URL
curl_exec($ch);
fclose($outFile);

// close CURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);  
ob_end_clean();`
```

Please correct me where am i wrong

Comment: slightly off topic but, where did you find the jpegmini REST API docs ?

Comment: http://www.jpegmini.com/server/docs#JPEGmini_for_AWS_REST_API_aws

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ec2-54-209-163-171.compute-1.amazonaws.com/api/v1/optimize');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: image/jpeg'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents("/tmp/input.jpg"));

$output_image = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// save your image from $output_image
```

Comment: Sabuj, i have uploaded the code used based on your suggestion but it is not working, Can you please help

Comment: Run the code again with enabling verbose. It will show you the details about how the things are going on. curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

Comment: I included the above statement, but has made no difference. I am still not getting any response. Tried using the Postman REST service chrome extension and it worked perfectly. But i am not able to implement it in PHP